# Facebook video on a post appears in a strange language

Tags: facebook, embed, videos, language

I don't know why it happens but, when I copy and paste a Facebook video URL inside my blog post, the language switch into Hindi or Indonesian (I don't really know)

https://prnt.sc/mlu83q
https://prnt.sc/mlueg1

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a localization problem, Facebook is loading a who-know-where javascript sdk to embed the video. Switch to code view inside your wordpress editor and search for the js include url, similar to `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5` this, and change whatever string appears instead of `en_US` with `en_US`.

Where the string is located depends on how you are doing the embedding.